# How to cleanup the derby instance running Hive metastore

Tags: apache-spark, hive, derby, apache-spark-sql

I went through multiple threads on SO which talks about migrating hive metastore to mysql in case multiple users want to access it. This case is different.

I'm trying run a hive program to execute a SQL on a dataset and then clean it up(close the context) to run another SQL on another dataset. But I see the error saying:

**ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database**

My question is- is there a way I can clean up the derby instance running hive metastore so that my next context initialization doesn't see the previous instance? I feel the situation is similar to running multiple unit tests and there should be a way to clean things up.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error while creating Data frames on Spark Shell:

> Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /metastore_db.

Cause:

I found that this is happening as there were multiple other instances of Spark-Shell already running and holding derby DB already, so when i was starting yet another Spark Shell and creating Data Frame on it using RDD.toDF() it was throwing error:

Solution:

I ran the ps command to find other instances of Spark-Shell:

```
ps -ef | grep spark-shell
```

and i killed them all using kill command:

```
kill -9 Spark-Shell-processID ( example: kill -9 4848)
```

after all the SPark-Shell instances were gone, i started a new SPark SHell and reran my Data frame function and it ran just fine :)